# Django can't get counted votes in template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to count and show how many votes every user gave. When i'm doing it in python console it shows me, but i can't get it from template.

In console:

```
from football_app.models import Score
from football_app.models import CustomUser

for user in CustomUser.objects.all():
    x = Score.objects.filter(granted_to=user).count()
    print(x)

0
1
1
1
1
1
```

0 because the request.user is not allowed to give himself a vote.

In views:

```
def test(request):
    data = dict()
    User = get_user_model()
    for user in User.objects.all():
        count_grades = Score.objects.filter(granted_to=user).count()
        data['count_grades'] = str(count_grades)
    return render(request, 'test.html', data)
```

test.html

```
{% for number_of_votes in count_grades %}
    {{ number_of_votes }}
{% endfor %}
```

or even

```
{{ count_grades }}
```

It shows me just `1`, that's all. Why isn't it showing for each user?

Comment: You only have one key in your data dictionary, it's getting overwritten inside the for loop. I'd recommend looking at Django model aggregates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset which are designed to solve this problem quite well, I don't know your schema but you could have something like: `User.objects.annotate(Count('scores'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a list and append grade count to it to display

```
data['count_grades'] = []
for user in User.objects.all():
    count_grades = Score.objects.filter(granted_to=user).count()
    data['count_grades'].append(str(count_grades))
```

Doing `data['count_grades'] = str(count_grades)` will overwrite the previous value. Because of this the last value `1` was getting displayed.

Comment: aha i understand, works like a charm, got one more question for you if you are willing to answer

Comment: Ok.. What's the question? I'll try to answer.

Comment: can you open a room so we can talk?

Comment: Join this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/143879/some-random-roon